# Limiting Decimal Places in Responses

Tags: java

I'm very new at Java and am really just experimenting with different things right now...mostly creating simple calculators just to practice using the language.  My question is, how do I limit the number of decimal places in a response to only 2 or 3 decimal places instead of what I am getting right now.  Here is the code I wrote for a Pythagorean Calculator...

Basically, I want "answer" to return a number with only a couple decimal places and I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks!

```
public class PythagoreanTheorem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double numOne, numTwo, aSquared, bSquared, cSquared, answer;

        System.out.println("Enter the value for Side-A: ");
        numOne = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the value for Side-B: ");
        numTwo = sc.nextDouble();

        aSquared = numOne * numOne;
        bSquared = numTwo * numTwo;
        cSquared = aSquared + bSquared;

        answer = Math.sqrt(cSquared);

        System.out.println("Side-C is: " + answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use **DecimalFormat class**

```
DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double twoDecimal =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(answer));
```

or **using BigDecimal**

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
d = answer.doubleValue();
```

or **without BigDecimal**

```
d = Math.round(d*100)/100.0d;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [format `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and something like

```
System.out.printf("Side-C is: %.3f%n", answer);
```

which will get 3 decimal places.